# $_FILES - Segurança

Tags: php, file-upload

Por que o $_FILES ficam vazios se o arquivo for um bloqueado(Baixado)? Por exemplo um pdf ou uma imagem que quando baixadas possui as seguintes propriedades:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se existe uma forma de resolver esses problemas para fazer upload, o que devo fazer?

Comment: Voce selecionou ele e mandou via formulario nas nao chegar no servidor?

Comment: Não, ele simplesmente usa o move_upload_files, enviando pra um diretório local e salvando apenas o caminho na base de dados.